# SVN not installing on Netbeans

Tags: c++, windows, svn, netbeans

In Netbeans I want to setup some sort of version control system so I can revert back if I break the code. I'm working by myself and not sharing the code with others. I tried setting up SVN but the [instructions](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/ide/subversion.html) don't work. They link to the following site where you can download the SVN software but then the site just links back to the Netbeans download section.

> Subversion client software ([download](http://www.open.collab.net/downloads/netbeans/))

How do you get SVN working with Netbeans? By the way, atm I'm doing C++ development.

Answer (score 0):

In the main page, there is a link. Did you try this?

http://www.collab.net/downloads/subversion